# Animate automatic UILabel text size change

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

I have set my UILabel to scale text automatically to fit within the labels frame. During runtime I am changing the size of this frame to make space for things underneath, but I really want the size change to be animated, since the text jumps from one size to a smaller one, which doesn't look very good.

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: The guy in the question mentioned is changing the font size of his label manually, while my font size changes automatically based on the label size, using a minimum font scale.

Comment: No difference. Just need to use a param.

Comment: What? There is no code changing the font size

Comment: Okay, maybe post some of your relevant code about how you change your label then.

Comment: I dont use any code to change the label size. All done with autolayout - selecting "minimum font scale" in the attribute inspector.

Comment: You mentioned this: " During runtime I am changing the size of this frame to make space for things underneath". How do you change the size of the frame?

Comment: The label has constraints added. if the textview underneath is made taller, the labels height will reduce. All I am doing is changing the height of my text field

Comment: okay, then you need to add animation for that -- changing the height of the text field. If you can provide a minimal reproachable example, maybe we could jump in and help. Otherwise, that's the best advice I can give now. You need to add animation to whatever code that trigger your UILabel's frame size change. If it is changed by constraints, it is okay too. Normally, the view animation will be able to calculate that properly for you.

Comment: I am already animating the height change of the textview, and the frame height of the label changes like expected. The thing I am looking for is the change in font size to be animated

Answer (score 0):

To animate the height change use `UIView.animateWithDuration`. Here's an example animating the height change of a `UILabel` with a 2 second duration:

```
@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()

  let updatedHeight: CGFloat = 100.0
  let updatedFrame = CGRect(origin:label.frame.origin,
    size: CGSize(width:label.frame.width, height: updatedHeight))

  UIView.animateWithDuration(2.0, animations: {
    self.label.frame = updatedFrame
  })
}
```

Comment: This is not what I am looking for. I am already animating the height change l - what I am looking for is animating the automatic font size change that happens after the label has been resized, to fit the text properly.

Comment: Since you are reducing the UILabels height could you use a transform instead? `let labelScale = updatedLabelFrame.height / originalLabelFrame.height` `self.label.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(self.label.transform, labelScale, labelScale)` This will give you the [following animation](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Oyk9H.gif) when inside of  `UIView.animateWithDuration`